# HTML Cell Button

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, href

I've a problem where I can't get my cell look like a button. I use a table as navbar, and I want the cell to be a button.

For the HTML part:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="maintablewrapper_table01">
            <tr class="maintablewrapper_tr01">
                <th class="maintablewrapper_tr01_th01" colspan="6">Site Header<br><br>Head</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="maintablewrapper_tr02">
                <td class="tdlink" onclick="window.location('http://www.google.com');">Home</td>
                <td>Producten</td>
                <td>Diensten</td>
                <td>Over ons</td>
                <td>Informatie</td>
                <td>Contact</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Help much appreciated

Comment: "I use a table as navbar." — Please don't. A nav bar is (semantically) a list of links for navigation. HTML has elements for navigation, lists and links.

Comment: You want it to look like a button. You need some CSS for that. Where is that? I agree with Quentin though, don't use a `<table>` for navigation.

Comment: Alright thanks, it was more of an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't put your CSS here or how you would want to see it, I have assumed the simplest.

This, at the roughest level, emulates what you might want to do.

**CSS :**

```
td {
    background:#bada55;
    color:#fff;
    border:10px solid #fff;
    padding:4px 10px;
}
```

Here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/550k4gm4/3/